# Finding minimum index of specific item in list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, minimum

I have a list of tuples with 3 items in each tuple. I'm looking to find the index position of the minimum value of all the third values in each tuple.

Here is a list of tuples as an example:

[(0, 3, 2), (4, 2, 6), (5, 1, 4), (2, 9, 8)]

The value I'm looking for is the index position in the list of 0, since the first tuple contains the minimum value of 2 for all the third items in the tuples.

EDIT: I know I could just take each value and put it into a new list, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` provides a very elegant solution for this.

```
ls = [(0, 3, 2), (4, 2, 6), (5, 1, 4), (2, 9, 8)]
ar = np.array(ls)
np.argmin(ar[:,2])
```

Gives you

```
0
```

Edit:

If your third element is a proper number and not a datetime, another possible numpy solution would be:

```
arr1 = np.array([a[2] for a in ls])
np.argmin(arr1)
```

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the response but I didn't mention that the first two values are actually datetimes, which can't be stored in numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new list `tuple_third_item_list` containing third element from each tuple in original list `list_item` and then find the min element's index from the newly created list.

```py
list_item = [(0, 3, 2), (4, 2, 6), (5, 1, 4), (2, 9, 8)]
tuple_third_item_list = [ i[2] for i in list_item]
min_element = min(tuple_third_item_list)
min_element_index = tuple_third_item_list.index(min_element)
print(min_element_index)
```

`min_element_index` gives the index of min value among all the third values from each tuple.